# map first object from api in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I map my arrays via

```
moviesList.map(movie => <MovieCard movieID={movie} key={movie}
```

but my API gives sometimes 1 or more results. How can I change my .map to show only the first result?

Comment: If you only want the first item then you likely do not want a .map at all.  To get the first item you can do `moviesList[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
[moviesList[0]].map(movie => <MovieCard movieID={movie} key={movie}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, writing moviesList[0].map will make your loop crash if [0] is an object, because it won't be iterable. So you basically need to get rid of all objects but the first one. You can do it with slice(). Here, slice(0,1) means "take all element from 0 to 1 in the array". So only the first object will survive. Then your map() will work like a charm. Also, the key is a basic number "i", obtained from map(), which is better than passing a whole object. If you want to use an object property for a key, please use something like movie.id, and not movies as a whole.

```js
moviesList.slice(0,1).map((movie,i)=> <<MovieCard movieID={movie} key={i}/>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
moviesList[0].map(movie=><MovieCard movieID={movie} key={movie}/> )
```

Or if you only want to show only one. Try this,

```
<MovieCard movieID={moviesList[0]} key={moviesList[0]}/>
```